# Raspberry Pi 3 Online Learning Topics

Tags: raspberry-pi

Anyone here can suggest a good online reference as a starting point to read and learn rpi3?

Possibility of using c++ or python as a reference programming language of used.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to actual search for this answer instead of posting it here. Anyway, [here](http://www.suntimebox.com/raspberry-pi-tutorial-course/) is a guide about Raspberry Pi.